# How to deal with already flagged questions in the Triage review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I came across a unique situation while win the Triage review queue. The question was a duplicate, and had already been flagged. It seems as though it was useless to flag it again, but that's the only acceptable answer.

Is this a glitch that should be fixed, so that such questions don't come up, or should such questions just be double flagged?

[image]